# Using interface builder is really a bad practice?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I  started developing for ios in a new company.
Here they taught me to never use iterface-builder, saying it's hard to maintenance the code and it have  a few limitations.

Using interface build for java application in netbeans i see a lot of "bad code" but i don't see it using IB, besides i see a lot of IB codes on the internet and only a few codes without it.

So for a large where no one is a beginner on ios development is a bad pratice use IB?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(Let me mention in advance that I have strong objection against using Interface Builder, for a number of reasons I will explain)

> Here they taught me to never use Interface Builder, saying it's hard to maintain the code and it has a few limitations.

This is only partially true. The principal reason I don't like Interface Builder and Xcode in general is that **a lot of** beginner programmers think that it is the only way for developing iOS/OS X apps. They have never heard of `gcc` and `clang`, they don't know what the compiler and linker error messages mean, they can't use `make`, and they have no idea about what the difference between the Objective-C language, the Cocoa (Touch) APIs, the IDE and the compiler is.

After all, they start using Interface Builder and Xcode with all of its quirky and sometimes strange/illogical features (and bugs as well), but when they're in the need of developing something non-obvious, they don't even realize there is a method for, for example, creating views and view controllers programmatically (yes, I've seen this very question on StackOverflow).

So, when abused (or rather, used too early), Interface Builder and all of the "convenient" features lead to programmers learning bad concepts and missing some important pieces of practice and experience.

**However, if you're a senior developer,** who has all the necessary skills, and you feel you could write an entire application from scratch, using just a simple text editor and a Makefile, then you are by all means permitted to use IB, and even encouraged to do so if you feel that's more comfortable than hammering out code.

So, to sum up:

> Using interface builder is really a bad practice?

No. Rather abusing it and not making the effort to learn the programmatic approach to UI stuff is bad practice.

Post scriptum: I have quite a lot of experience with iOS development, but I still find Interface Builder rather inconvenient and inconsistent. I generally use code for everything. But that seems to be my personal preference. One advantage is, however, that if one creates everything by code, then another programmer without access to these Apple-specific tools will be able to contribute to the project as well. This is a point where the "it's hard to maintain" part comes true...

For example, until I didn't have enough money for a Mac, I used Linux for developing iOS apps ([yes, that is actually possible](https://github.com/H2CO3/xchain-ios)). I couldn't use IB and Xcode, yet I have done loads of applications and tweaks (for jailbroken iOS, of course), and that was just fine.

Post scriptum #2: another reason for avoiding the use of IB could be the need for dynamic UIs. If you heavily rely on animations, custom UI elements, etc., it's hard to do everything in Interface Builder. Last summer, I had to rewrite a login screen of an application, and honestly, I don't know how I could have realize our designer's ideas if I had had to use Interface Builder. The UI/UX was so dynamic and it had so many ways to change that it was absolutely necessary to have fine control over each and every pixel. And that's something that code is better at than IB.

Comment: I disagree with the "you have to know everything about everything" argument. However, I do agree with the fact that you have to know WHEN to use IB and when not to use it. (and be able to do so). There are some powerful things you can do with IB and dynamic UIs (like the iPhoto UI that I mentioned with the animated brushes etc...) but you obviously have to complement them with actual code. I definitely don't think IB is bad practise though :-)

Comment: @Fogmeister Neither do I think it's bad practice, however if you want to call yourself a developer, you definitely **must** know what precisely is going on. Anyway, if you know something better, it saves a lot of time...

Comment: By the way, this is the exact reason why I hate when one tags general iOS- and OS X-related questions with the `xcode` tag. They're not at all related.

Comment: I upvoted all answer, and mark your answer as correct. First i understand it's not a bad practice. Second i agree with your personal opinion. Third now i understand why in our case IB it's a bad thing, the views in our project are very dynamic.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro I'm glad everything is clear to you now. Thanks, and have a nice day.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes I agree with you that if you are at initial stage of learning then you should do all by code. But once you have grasp on all the basic stuff then you can use `IB` to make your development fast and easy to maintain. At least that's my view :)

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes I too hate when people tag `xcode`. I don't think `xcode` tag is necessary in programming at all. Unless you struck with `xcode` (the software) related issues..

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Exactly! What the tag wiki for `xcode` says: "if this question wouldn't be different if you used `make` and `vi`, then you should not use this tag."

Comment: I find code-based views are more fluent, modular and "domain-driven". . IB-based views have a tendency to break MVC by providing fat-controllers, when the controller is supposed to be a thin glue between a rich model and a rich view. . instead we have an anorexic view and a fat controller. . With code-based views, we can have a rich, reusable interface.

Comment: @JasperBlues Exactly. Recently I've met an iOS developer friend of mine, and we were discussing exactly the issue of over-sized controllers.

Comment: @H2CO3 So we could 'fix' this by using a composition of many views in the Xibs. . However, IB only provides visual feedback for sub-classes, and not custom classes composed of other views. . And this leads to the composition vs inheritance problem. . It would be nice if you could assign a design asset image to the custom class, for some visual feedback, otherwise its just blue boxes. . So there's a choice - forego good design and reuse for some drag-n-drop, or not? There's ways to work around these drawbacks, I guess, but I'd rather not fight it for complex apps. . Nice for quick prototyping.

Comment: @JasperBlues Yeah, that's it. IB is good for quick prototyping. Not so good for anything serious beyond that. (Last summer's experience, actually. Fancy animations and stuff don't play well with XIBs.)

Comment: Well said. After 8 months of wondering why Android was so much better, I finally discovered I was allowed to forego the IB. Apple should not 'teach you swift' by using IB. Added to that, their documentation and lack of openness, and unexplained arbitrary decisions, make being an iOS developer hilariously frustrating - "sorry we can't release as that checkbox that I unchecked somewhere breaks everything and I can't find it and google keeps giving me Apple's learn swift home page"

Answer (score 6):

I strongly disagree with the idea that IB is a bad practice. Interface Builder has the following advantages over code:

- when working with complex (and even simple) graphical interfaces, **IB cuts the code down to a mere fraction** - for example, simply creating a button in IB takes a few seconds, whereas in code, that translates to dozens of lines, especially if the button is to be styled
- using autoresizing masks for **supporting multiple resolutions and devices is a breeze** - this is important as Apple is now pushing towards resolution-independent apps
- changing/tweaking properties of views is a **matter of a few clicks** rather than lines of code, especially if working with images

However, there is one disadvantage (that comes to my mind):

- it can **hard to pinpoint** what might be causing a graphical problem, since it will be hidden away in in the IB file than in the code

Comment: 1. Use a category for styling and you only need to worry about styling your buttons in one place.
3. Those few clicks usually translate to just a few lines of code. Clicking and scrolling takes far longer than writing a few lines of code involving autocompletion. Plus there's less fragmentation and searching for the right files and check marks in IB can take forever.

Comment: 1. A button is not a "complex graphical interface" it is a simple user interface element. When a UIButton is created and modified via the interface builder and later dynamically strange things occurr not to mention that when using .xibs especially if there are many dynamic buttons. 2. This is true , but if again you UI elements get animated I EXPECT you get in a word of pain (I have no real expirience). 3. That is apsolutely true with a HUGE BUT and WTF. Many properties are incorrectly set by default causing strange errors and sometimes the UI element does not respond to the change...

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely not. Interface Builder is a really powerful way of creating UI really quickly. Especially with Storyboards it allows you to make functional apps with very little code.

The issue of it "creating bad code" is rubbish as the IB doesn't create any code. The files it creates are essentially XML files that complement the code that you write.

Most of the apps I've developed have been mostly started on IB.

Obviously, you can't do the FUNCTIONAL stuff of your app.  I.e. you can't tell a button exactly what to do. But you can point it to a function that you have written and get a working button with almost no code.

Most of the UI in iPhoto on iPad and iPhone is written in Interface Builder.

Comment: I would very much count xibs as code. they contain instructions and translate In The end to 'binary commands for cpu' -- they are interpreted 'just like' java byte code

Comment: I guess you are right. I have seen many WYSIWYG editors that create actual code that you can then go and edit in your actual implementation files. (I know you can edit XIBs). That's what I interpreted as "bad code".

Answer (score 4):

Much has been said, but I am still going to give my 2 cents for this discussion...

Until some point I agree with [H2CO3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3), it's better to understand what's going under the hood, than keep using shortcuts to achieve something. That works most of the time, the thing, and that's where I strongly disagree with [H2CO3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3), is the following:

- Most of the people that use a technology (C#, Java, HTML, iOS, etc), they use it because their Company needs them to use it, because someone else is actually going to pay you to work with that. And not because you actually woke up in the middle of the night and suddenly had the urge to learn C.
- If someone asks you tomorrow to create an iOS App and you never developed for iOS before, I truly doubt you are going to create an App from  scratch without using XIB's or Storyboards (Which I hate btw).

What H2CO3 proposes is a utopia... Where you really understand what is going on beneath, but because you are such a "leet", you are able to use shortcuts, like XIBs. Well,  things don't work that way, and sooner or later you will have to do some shitty thing to deliver something on the next morning.

I prefer, and that's personal perspective, to use a XIB, than to use the first 3rd party library that comes in front of me. And I think that's more reasonable than doing an interface by hand. I prefer to understand the code, and do it by myself, than using for instance a library to help me download/upload stuff.

For wrapping this up, **my advise to the person that asked this is:**

Try to understand why things are done the way they are. Above all, try to be a better programmer in each new project that you face. If something new comes up (new iOS version) spend a day or two to see what's new, and what could you use. XIB's are perfectly fine to be used, but spend some time creating `UIView's` by hand, so you can see all the flexibility they give you. And above all, run away from Storyboards (^^)

**P.S:** A senior developer it's not just a guy that has a "better Kung fu than you".. It's more than that.